# Event Handlers in a JavaScript "class"

Tags: javascript, oop

I am working at fully understanding class definitions in JavaScript. Currently, I have a class defined like the following:

```
function Item() { this.init(); }
Item.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        this.data = {
            id: 0,
            name: "",
            description: ""     
        }
    },

    save: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: getUrl(),
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(this.data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: save_Succeeded,
            error: save_Failed
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is, I'm not sure how, or where, to define my `save_Succeeded` and `save_Failed` event handlers. Can someone please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: inside the `Item`. where else can it be?

Comment: If you're defining a new prototype object, don't forget to add the property `constructor: Item`.

Comment: What is this "constructor: Item"? This is the first I've ever heard of that. Do you have an article or something that I can use to learn about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `context:` to your `$.ajax` call pointing to `this` so that the correct object is passed as `this` when the handlers are called.

Something like:

```
save: function() {
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        url: getUrl(),
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(this.data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: this.save_Succeeded,
        error: this.save_Failed
    });
```

(assuming that you also put `save_Succeeded` and `save_Failed` into the `prototype`)
    }

Comment: Can you please give me a sample? I don't fully understand what you're saying.